# rust: Define a trait that returns a non consuming iterator. (associated type bounds for both T impls IntoIterator and &T impls IntoIterator)

Tags: rust

I want a trait that returns a generic collection and let me iterate over the references in that collection.

e.g:

```
trait DuckCollection {
    type CollectionType: IntoIterator<Item=Duck>;
    fn get(self) -> Self::CollectionType;
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &Self::CollectionType;
}
```

The consuming iterator works, however there is a problem with `as_ref`.

```
//doesn't work
fn print<T: DuckCollection>(model: &T) {
    let collection_ref = model.as_ref();
    for itemref in (collection_ref).into_iter() {
        println!("{:?}", *itemref);
    }  
}
```

This doesn't work because when `.into_iter()` is called on `collection_ref`, `collection_ref` is coerced from `&<T as DuckCollection>::CollectionType` to `<T as DuckCollection>::CollectionType` because `DuckCollection` does not know that `&<T as DuckCollection>::CollectionType` also implements `IntoIterator`

[image]

This can be fixed by adding trait bounds to the function. i.e, the below works:

```
fn print<'a, T: DuckCollection>(model: &'a T)
where &'a<T as DuckCollection>::CollectionType: IntoIterator<Item=&'a Duck>
{
    let collection_ref = model.as_ref();
    for itemref in collection_ref.into_iter() {
        println!("{:?}", *itemref);
    }  
}
```

However, I would like to have this information in the trait itself, rather than in the code that uses it, so I tried to use a `where` clause in the trait return type, shown below, with the resulting error:

```
impl DuckCollection for Model {
    type CollectionType = Vec<Duck>;
    fn get(self) -> Self::CollectionType {
        self.data
    }
    fn as_ref<'a>(&'a self) -> &Self::CollectionType where &'a<Self>::CollectionType: IntoIterator<Item=&'a Duck> {
        &self.data
    }
}

fn print<T: DuckCollection>(model: &T)
{
    let collection_ref = model.as_ref();
    for itemref in collection_ref.into_iter() {
        println!("{:?}", *itemref);
    }  
}

`&<T as DuckCollection>::CollectionType` is not an iterator
the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `&<T as DuckCollection>::CollectionType`
required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `&<T as DuckCollection>::CollectionType`
```

The type is no longer being coerced, but it still doesn't realise that `&<T as DuckCollection>::CollectionType` is an `IntoIterator`. (i.e both `Vec<T>` and `&Vec<T>` impl `IntoIterator`). This is annoying because I'm pretty sure my `where` clause tells the compiler this.

I've also tried using `associated_type_defaults` and `generic_associated_types`, to tell the trait that there is an associated type called `CollectionTypeRef`, that implement `IntoIterator`, and that the type is a reference of a `CollectionType`. Shown below with the error:

```
trait DuckCollection {
    type CollectionType: IntoIterator<Item=Duck>;
    type CollectionTypeRef<'a>: IntoIterator<Item=&'a Duck> = &'a Self::CollectionType;
    fn get(self) -> Self::CollectionType;
    fn as_ref<'a>(&self) -> Self::CollectionTypeRef<'a>;
}

the associated type `<Self as DuckCollection>::CollectionType` may not live long enough
...so that the reference type `&'a <Self as DuckCollection>::CollectionType` does not outlive the data it points at
```

How can I fix this? How can I tell the trait that `get` returns something that can be turned into an iterator of `Duck`, and `as_ref` returns an iterator of `&Duck` ?

Answer (score 1):

Typical, as soon as I post the question I figure out the answer.

See below for the full solution. I would still like to know if there is a more elegant way of doing this.

This still requires me to put `type CollectionTypeRef<'a> = &'a Self::CollectionType;` in the impl, and I'd rather that be a `associated_type_default` but that doesn't seem to work.

```
//#![feature(associated_type_defaults)]
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Duck;

trait DuckCollection {
    type CollectionType: IntoIterator<Item=Duck>;
    type CollectionTypeRef<'a>: IntoIterator<Item= &'a Duck> where Self: 'a;
    fn get(self) -> Self::CollectionType;
    fn as_ref<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::CollectionTypeRef<'a>;
}

struct Model {data: Vec<Duck>}

impl DuckCollection for Model {
    type CollectionType = Vec<Duck>;
    type CollectionTypeRef<'a> = &'a Self::CollectionType;

    fn get(self) -> Self::CollectionType {
        self.data
    }
    fn as_ref<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::CollectionTypeRef<'a> {
        &self.data
    }
}

fn print<T: DuckCollection>(model: &T)
{
    let collection_ref = model.as_ref();
    for itemref in collection_ref.into_iter() {
        println!("{:?}", *itemref);
    }  
}

fn main() {
    let model = Model {
        data: vec![Duck, Duck],
    };

    print(&model);
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```